# Write image as external style using CSS

Tags: css

I have HTML code as below:

```
<img src="../images/ffp.jpg" alt="Adiscos membre de la F&eacute;d&eacute;ration de la Formation Professionnelle" name="Adiscos membre de la F&eacute;d&eacute;ration de la Formation Professionnelle" width="100" id="Adiscos membre de la F&eacute;d&eacute;ration de la Formation Professionnelle" />
```

I want to write it as external CSS. How should do with this?

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible with CSS. The image's source is part of the markup, not CSS. You need to use JavaScript.

```
 document.getElementById("ImageID").src = "ImageSource";
```

But if you really need CSS to be doing this, use DIVs instead.

`<div id="image1"></div>`

```
/* In external CSS file */
#image1 { width: 100px; height: 50px; background-image: url(image.gif); }
```

Comment: But using DIVS you'll lose the ability to set an ALT tag, resize printing (many browsers don't print background images) and Search Enginge indexing.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer but  how I display `alt` , `name` , `id` use as external?

Comment: @Maly.itcCute  You can't use ALT and NAME if you use div.Thats why you should use JavaScript.
`<img src=".." alt=".." id="image1" name="image1" />`

Answer (score 0):

.classname{background:url(../images/ffp.jpg) no-repeat;}

Answer (score 0):

```
Adiscos membre de la F&eacute;d&eacute;ration de la Formation Professionnelle {
background-image:url(""../images/ffp.jpg");
width : 100;
}
```